# Raise event on control

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, win-universal-app

We need to be able to intercept `PointerPressed` event on the `WebView` but since it won't fire and Universal Apps lack `Preview...` events and we only need mouse wheel interaction, we thought we could add another control, say a canvas, on top of the `WebView` and pass its `PointerWheelChanged` event to the `WebView`.

In WPF, this could easily be done using `RaiseEvent` method. How are we supposed to achieve the same in UWP?